# Count all possible paths in a graph database for multiple vertices

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin

I have a graph db and I need to get all the vertices that doesn't have any out edges and count how many vertices lead to each one

ex.

I have 8 vertices A,B1,B2,D, X,Y1,Y2,Z

D->B1->A

B2->A

Z->Y1->X

Y2->X

I would like to get a list the would have [A = 3, X = 3] plus the properties of each vertex

why 3? cause you can get to A from D, B1, and B2

what I have so far is to get the count of paths of one vertex but doing that query for each one is a bit slow, so I would like one query that will give me all that info

```
g.V().not(outE()).repeat(inE().outV().simplePath()).emit().dedup().count().next()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you had the right query, just need to add `group` to it:

```
g.V().not(outE()).group()
.by(label())
.by(repeat(inE().outV().simplePath()).emit().dedup().count())
```

I tested it [here](https://gremlify.com/1r).  seems to work as expected

Comment: amazing! thanks. any chance to also get all the properties of each vertex?

Comment: For the 'A' & 'X'? if you want more data I would use `project` step

Comment: yeah just for A and X. is it better to do it in a single query (in which I'll read about the project step) or to do it in 2 queries?

Comment: you need to test it on your data and your DB provider, you can try running `project('data', 'count').by(elementMap()).by(repeat...)`

Comment: yeah, I just read about it a bit and made is work. Perfect! thank you!

Comment: @noam621 thanks for using Gremlify to share your query, this kind of use cases really helps us improve. If you have any feedback to share, please do!